# set of Kolmogorov-random strings is co-re

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, kolmogorov-complexity

given  R<sub>C</sub> = {x : C(x) ≥ |x|} is a set of  Kolmogorov-random strings.

How can I show that  R<sub>C</sub>  is co-re

I have been reading this paper [What Can be Efficiently Reduced to the
Kolmogorov-Random Strings?](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.5.4608&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which just says that we know that by Kum96 we know that R<sub>C</sub> is Co-re

I was not able to find the proof of how that is proved

Answer (score 1):

There is a procedure to enumerate $\{ x : C(x) \lt \vert x \vert \}$, the set of all strings with descriptions shorter than themselves: evaluate every description (in parallel) to see what string it describes, and output that string if it is longer than its description.  One way to do this is: on time step $t = 2^k \cdot (2 \cdot x + 1)$, spend a unit of time evaluating the $k^{th}$ description.  So this set is recursively enumerable and therefore its complement $R_c$ is in co-RE.