# not any computable function f such that x is not in the Halting Problem iff f ( x ) belongs to set of Kolmogorov-random strings

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, kolmogorov-complexity

taking clue from this question [set of Kolmogorov-random strings is co-re](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542993/set-of-kolmogorov-random-strings-is-co-re/1543010#1543010)

the paper mentioned in the above link talks about the non existence  of a computable function

how can I show that there is not any one-one computable function f such that x is not in the Halting Problem iff f ( x ) belongs  to R<sub>C</sub>

R<sub>C</sub> = {x : C(x) ≥ |x|} is a set of Kolmogorov-random strings.

Comment: Can you give a precise definition of "$x$ is not in the Halting Problem" ?

Answer (score 0):

@xoff 
The paper [What Can be Efficiently Reduced to the Kolmogorov-Random Strings?](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.5.4608&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
Talks about this question in the second page of the paper
this is what the paper says

That is, the halting problem can be solved by a machine
that, on input x , computes a set of queries to R <sub>C</sub> and then uses the answers to those  queries to decide whether x is in the halting problem. It is important to note that in this  weak-truth-table reduction, there is
no computable bound  that can be placed on the time used by the oracle machine, for the part of the computation that takes place after the
queries are answered.)  This was improved significantly by Kummer.

I also went searched through the kum96 paper but was not able to make much sense out of it